# Print strings that can be formed with two strings

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve the below problem. But could not come up with a correct solution

Given two strings say `xyz` and `abc`. Find all the strings that can be formed with these two strings. One constraint is that the sequence of characters in each string should remain the same.

Examples:

```
xyabzc - Valid

xabcyz - Valid

abcxyz - Valid

xyzacb - Invalid. (b cannot come before c)
```

I tried the following,

Concatenated both the strings into a new string. Got all the permutations of the string and removed the one's that are not following the above constraint. I know this is very vague but that's the only solution I came up.

Please suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this problem very easily with recursion. In each step, you can either add a character from the first string or a character from the second string.

C++ code -

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string s1, s2;  //Input strings
vector <string> v;  //To store resultant strings

void merge_strings(int i,int j,string res)
{
        if(i == s1.length() && j == s2.length())
                v.push_back(res);
        if(i < s1.length())
                merge_strings(i + 1,j,res + s1[i]);
        if(j < s2.length())
                merge_strings(i,j + 1,res + s2[j]);
}

int main()
{
        s1 = "abc";
        s2 = "xyz";
        merge_strings(0,0,"");
        for(string s : v)
                cout << s << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output -

```
abcxyz
abxcyz
abxycz
abxyzc
axbcyz
axbycz
axbyzc
axybcz
axybzc
axyzbc
xabcyz
xabycz
xabyzc
xaybcz
xaybzc
xayzbc
xyabcz
xyabzc
xyazbc
xyzabc
```

Comment: Man I was thinking to solve this iteratively for last 2 hours and you solved it recursively like a champ. Thanks a lot.